# I cannot initiate an integer vector in C++

Tags: c++

I have the following code excerpt.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
using namespace std;

int solver(int T)
{
    /* read IA */

    ifstream inputFile("IA [0;1.3077].txt");

    vector<int> ia;

    if (inputFile) {
        int num;
        while ( inputFile >> num) {
            ia.push_back(num);
        }
    }

}

int main (void) {
    solver(360);
}
```

But it gives me this error:

```
 error: implicit instantiation of undefined template
      'std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >'
    vector<int> ia;
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/iosfwd:200:29: note: 
      template is declared here
class _LIBCPP_TYPE_VIS_ONLY vector;
```

The goal is to read a txt file with integers per line without knowing how many lines there are in advance. I'm choosing a vector to hold the data because I don't want to initialize an integer array with a fixed size. Does anybody have any suggestions?

Also, I understand that the variable `T` is unused - I will use it after the .txt file is loaded.

Comment: Have you posted ALL the code? Obviously, not.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: @RichardCritten Just did.

Comment: You need to `#include <vector>`

Comment: What is the point of the argument here `solver(int T)` ?

Comment: Apart from missing vector header 

What is the return of your function  ??


    int solver(int T)
    {
        /* read IA */
    
        ifstream inputFile("IA [0;1.3077].txt");
    
        vector<int> ia;
    
        if (inputFile) {
            int num;
            while ( inputFile >> num) {
                ia.push_back(num);
            }
        }
    
    }

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: @Caleth this is a compiler error, not a linker error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to:

```
 #include <vector>
```

You must alway include directly all the headers for the types you use.